# How to test Unity Coroutines in Unity Test Runner

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-game-engine, coroutine, test-runner

I'm currently developing a game in Unity 2019 and C# and I use a lot of events and coroutines for it. The coroutines are necessary because many calculations are done in them and I don't want the game to freeze during that time. Now I started to write unit tests using the Test Runner (Play Mode) and the **coroutines are just not executed**. Since I really need to be sure that they work as expected, it's not possible to just test "on the higher level".

I already tried the normal StartCoroutine() method, which doesn't work in the test file ("method name not found"). Moreover, I refactored one of my coroutines to be a normal void method and everything worked well and it passed the test. I used the Visual Studio debugger to see if it jumps into the coroutine execution and it does not. So the problem clearly is, that the coroutines are not executed. I thought about moving the calculation logic to another void function and test this function (and leave out the coroutine), but I must be sure that the iterations done in the coroutine work as well (they usually are more complicated than in the example).

This is a minimal example showing the general structure (there are usually many more computations done).

```
public class MeasuredValues
{
    List<Vector3> slidingWindow; // this is already filled when Normalize() is executed

    public IEnumerator Normalize()
    {
        //find coordinate system origin
        Vector3 originPosition = GetOrigin(); // returns a Vector3
        //normalization
        for (int i = 0; i < slidingWindow.Count; i++)
        {
            yield return null;
            //reset point to be at (0,y,0)
            slidingWindow[i] -= originPosition;
        }
    }
}
```

In the test file I want to:

```
[Test]
public void TestNormalization()
{
    MeasuredValues myMeasuredValues = new MeasuredValues();
    // add many Vector3 to slidingWindow
    // call coroutine
    // assert, that the values are now as expected
}
```

I tried `myMeasuredValues.Normalize()` (didn't work, the debugger just jumped over it) and `StartCoroutine(myMeasuredValues.Normalize)` (didn't work, the StartCoroutine is not available in that context).
Finally, I tried

```
    while (test.Normalize().MoveNext())
    {
        yield return null;
    }
```

but this never ends since the `MoveNext()` is never set to false. At least the debugger jumped into the coroutine method.

**Is there any easily applicable solution to test my coroutines with Visual Studio or Unity Test Runner without the need to refactor the whole project structure?**

Answer (score 3):

> I tried `myMeasuredValues.Normalize()` (didn't work, the debugger just jumped over it)

that one is of course since this is not how you run a coroutine

> and `StartCoroutine(myMeasuredValues.Normalize)` (didn't work, the StartCoroutine is not available in that context).

that is due to [`StartCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) is a member of `MonoBehaviour`.

---

**UPDATE**

Actually using [`[UnityTest]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.test-framework@1.3/manual/reference-attribute-unitytest.html) instead of `[Test]` you can simply use

```
[UnityTest]
public IEnumerator TestNormalization()
{
    MeasuredValues myMeasuredValues = new MeasuredValues();

    // add many Vector3 to slidingWindow
    
    yield return myMeasuredValues.Normalize();

    // assert, that the values are now as expected
}
```

since this way the test is executed by the framework as a Coroutine itself.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you can call a coroutine in your tests like this:

```
yield return myMeasuredValues.Normalize();
// Assert values are as expected
```

At least I managed to test coroutines in my Playmode tests this way (using Unity 2021.3.8), without the need of a `TestRoutineRunner` as [derHugo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58746536/1329142) suggested in 2019.

It seems not to be necessary to use `MonoBehavior.StartCoroutine()` to start the coroutine, as long as you *use* the return value (in this case with `yield return`). I'm not at all a Unity expert, so I'm only guessing, but perhaps this behavior is due to the fact that a `[UnityTest]` itself is called as a coroutine by Unity's TestRunner.

Unfortunately I did not find any proper documentation for this behavior. I'm just happy that after days of trial and error I got my own tests working. Please add a comment if you know more details, caveats, and/or have a link to documentation or helpful background info.

Comment: Hey indeed back then I either didn't know `[UnityTest]` or it didn't exist yet. But yes, this is THE way to go and my original solution was quite hacky ;)

Comment: As to why the `yield return` works this way - This is nothing Unity specific. Unity actually "ab"uses the `IEnumerator` interface for their Coroutines. A Coroutine basically just means it is registered somewhere to receive a `MoveNext` call each frame until it reaches the end. So just the same you do `yield return null;` or `yield return new WaitForSeconds();` you can `yield` anything that is an `IEnumerator` or implements `GetEnumerator` - or some other types handled especially via extensions etc